# Create hierachical Tree with SQL

Tags: sql-server, recursion, tree

I have the follwoing situation. I Have a table with company groups and a table with company groups assigned to other company groups.

Table with all company groups:

```
CompanyGroupName    |   SomeOtherData
---                 |   ---
CompanyGroupA       |   ...
CompanyGroupB       |   ...
CompanyGroupC       |   ...
CompanyGroupD       |   ...
CompanyGroupE       |   ...
CompanyGroupF       |   ...
CompanyGroupG       |   ...
CompanyGroupH       |   ...
...                 |   ...
```

Table with assigned company groups:

```
CompanyGroupParent  |   CompanyGroupChild
---                 |   ---
CompanyGroupA       |   CompanyGroupB
CompanyGroupD       |   CompanyGroupE
CompanyGroupF       |   CompanyGroupG
CompanyGroupB       |   CompanyGroupC
CompanyGroupE       |   CompanyGroupG
...                 |   ...
```

What I want is a list with the structure of

```
TOP Level       |   Level 1         |   Level 2         |   Level N
CompanyGroupA   |   CompanyGroupB   |   CompanyGroupC   |   ...
CompanyGroupD   |   CompanyGroupE   |   CompanyGroupG
CompanyGroupF   |   CompanyGroupG
CompanyGroupH
```

What I already figured out is that I can/should!? use CTE and recursive statements.

Therefore I need to identify the anchor elements. Which is relativly easy as if a Company group is not listed as a Child it is automaticaly an root element. The used statement returns me the resultset

```
TOP Level       |   Level 1         
CompanyGroupA   |   NULL
CompanyGroupD   |   NULL
CompanyGroupF   |   NULL
CompanyGroupH   |   NULL
```

What I do not understand now, is how to build up the `UNION ALL` part of the recursive statement to get the desired output.

The key point is, that the tree may have multiple root elements and an unkown depth of levels.

Would be nice if someone could help me on that.

Thx in advance
Alex

Answer (score 0):

A recursive query alone will not be sufficient for the complete solution. The companies must be pivoted to their respective level column and because your number of result columns is variable, you will require dynamic SQL.

**Sample data**

```
create table CompanyGroups
(
  Child  nvarchar(7),
  Parent nvarchar(7)
);

insert into CompanyGroups (Child, Parent) values
('Comp100', null     ),
('Comp110', 'Comp100'),
('Comp111', 'Comp110'),
('Comp120', 'Comp100'),
('Comp200', null     ),
('Comp210', 'Comp200'),
('Comp211', 'Comp210'),
('Comp300', null     ),
('Comp400', null     ),
('Comp410', 'Comp400'),
('Comp420', 'Comp400');
```

**Solution**

This bit produces the `Level` for each company.

```
with rcte as
(
  select cg.Child as Company,
         0 as Level
  from CompanyGroups cg
  where cg.Parent is null
    union all
  select cg.Child,
         r.Level + 1
  from rcte r
  join CompanyGroups cg
    on cg.Parent = r.Company
)
select r.Level, r.Company
from rcte r
order by r.Level, r.Company;
```

This would be a non-dynamic pivot of the previous information for 3 levels (`0`, `1`, `2`). Pivoting this information also requires an extra `RowNum` column.

```
with rcte as
(
  select cg.Child as Company,
         0 as Level
  from CompanyGroups cg
  where cg.Parent is null
    union all
  select cg.Child,
         r.Level + 1
  from rcte r
  join CompanyGroups cg
    on cg.Parent = r.Company
),
data as
(
  select r.Level,
         row_number() over(partition by r.Level order by r.Company) as RowNum,
         r.Company
  from rcte r
)
select p.[0] as LVL0,
       p.[1] as LVL1,
       p.[2] as LVL2
from data d
pivot (max(d.Company) for d.Level in ([0], [1], [2])) p;
```

Now for the final step, transformating the distinct level numbers to substrings and plugging those into a dynamic SQL statement that handles `N` levels.

```
-- get level list substrings
declare @selectList nvarchar(100);
declare @pivotList nvarchar(100);

with rcte as
(
  select cg.Child as Company,
         0 as Level
  from CompanyGroups cg
  where cg.Parent is null
    union all
  select cg.Child,
         r.Level + 1
  from rcte r
  join CompanyGroups cg
    on cg.Parent = r.Company
),
lvls as
(
  select r.Level
  from rcte r
  group by r.Level
)
select @selectList = string_agg('p.[' + convert(nvarchar(3), l.Level) + '] as LVL' + convert(nvarchar(3), l.Level), ', ') within group (order by l.Level),
       @pivotList = string_agg('[' + convert(nvarchar(3), l.Level) + ']', ', ') within group (order by l.Level)
from lvls l;

-- merge substrings in statement
declare @stmt nvarchar(2000) = 
'with rcte as
(
  select cg.Child as Company,
         0 as Level
  from CompanyGroups cg
  where cg.Parent is null
    union all
  select cg.Child,
         r.Level + 1
  from rcte r
  join CompanyGroups cg
    on cg.Parent = r.Company
),
data as
(
  select r.Level,
         row_number() over(partition by r.Level order by r.Company) as RowNum,
         r.Company
  from rcte r
)
select ' + @selectList + '
from data d
pivot (max(d.Company) for d.Level in (' + @pivotList + ')) p;'
    
-- execute statement
exec (@stmt);
```

**Result**

```
LVL0    LVL1    LVL2
------- ------- -------
Comp100 Comp110 Comp111
Comp200 Comp120 Comp211
Comp300 Comp210 null
Comp400 Comp410 null
null    Comp420 null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8900c3d873e6a7da8db2dca0bbdc974e) to see everything in action.